2024 Q1 Activity Support
I'm opening another opportunity to request support for asking and answering questions on our site.
I will be accepting proposals here until Friday, February 23rd. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a user's proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
I have some ideas I've been mulling over, but I'd love to spread this support around to support the community as much as possible.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2024 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work before the end of May.

For this support request, we are restricted to the following:

667 EUR
10 items total, up to 5 copies of the same set
Maximum of 5 addresses on the request

Here are some possible ideas that I think would be valuable:

Answer an unanswered question. If there's a question that a set doesn't directly help you answer, that's alright. An unrelated set can still be provided as a "thank you" for your contribution.
We have 21 questions related to the D11. Many are unanswered and are likely at least partial duplicates. If someone wants to clean these up in some fashion, that would be great. I don't have the set, and we can't get it via a support request as it is out of production, but an alternative "thank you" set could be provided.
Motorize the Orient Express train set
Explore the sound brick in the Sorting Hat
Analyze the physical accuracy of Planet Earth and Moon in Orbit


Dang, I missed it this time around. Is it still possible to join this time, or will I have to wait until next time?

@MatthewJensen This support has already been requested and arrived, so you'll have to wait to get on the next one.

@MatthewJensen The Q3 support thread is up now if you are still interested: https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/2024-q3-activity-support

I'd gladly tackle the Earth and check just how accurate the model is compared to reality (sizes of the three bodies, distances, orbital parameters, rotation speeds, etc.) and which features got simplified away.

I'm happy to move forward with this. I'll work out the details with you via email.

@jncraton Just to be clear: in order to keep qualifying for the activity support program in the future, I should avoid using knock-off parts in my answer, right?

That's probably best. Would 3rd party elements enhance your answer in some way?

Since my only official, brand-new servo motor is broken, it would be a lot easier than to implement a return-to-center with a non-servo motor, but it's definitely doable. https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/18609/3631

That makes sense. I don't have a PF servo, so I'm not much help diagnosing this.
