2024 Q3 Activity Support
I'm opening another opportunity to request support for asking and answering questions on our site.
I will be accepting proposals here until Friday, August 2nd. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a user's proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2024 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work before the end of October.

For this support request, we are restricted to the following:

667 EUR
10 items total, up to 5 copies of the same set
Maximum of 5 addresses on the request


Do you actually mean May? I thought it would be closer.

@JenserCube That was incorrect and simply a copy-paste from last time. I have updated this to October, but there can be flexibility here.

I would like to have a go at answering this question about the rotor speed of 42145 Airbus H175 Rescue Helicopter.
PS: Thanks for the heads up for this Activity Support!

I'd be open to answering either Purpose of the four rubber tires in The Globe set (21332) or How to effectively attach mirrored stickers to an interior curved surface? - but since both sets are on the pricier end of the spectrum and the first question already has an answer in the comments, while the second is really a niche topic, none of these would be a priority even in my eyes.
